# Can I choose area when Scaffolding in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

How do I run MvcScaffold in an area in asp.net mvc3? Is it even possible? I would like to execute something like:

```
Scaffold Controller MyModel --area MyArea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use one dash instead `-Area`

> -Area : If you want the generated files to go into a specific ASP.NET MVC area, enter its name here. Note that you must have created that area already; the scaffolder doesn’t create areas automatically (yet).

[Source](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/)